# The ban command doesn't do what it's supposed to do

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I try to run my command, instead of the errors I specified, I get the errors from the console and the result is: `Failed to ban the user` and the console says `DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.` and/or `missing permissions`.  But if I try to ban myself with an account that has no rights, I get banned myself. So if I do tryfyfu `/ban user: @tryfyfu` with my acc (the account without rights) I can still ban myself but the bot should actually say: "❌ | You can't ban a user from the guild!" answer and so it is with the other functions like `invalid member`or `❌ | You can't ban yourself` and so on Here's the code. Would be nice if someone could help me.

```
const {
    Client,
    CommandInteraction,
    Message,
    MessageEmbed,
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Ban a user',
    options: [
        {
            name: "user",
            description: "Choose the user to ban.",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "reason for punishment",
            type: "STRING",
            required: false
        }
    ],
    run: async (client, interaction, options) => {
        const member = interaction.options.getMember("user")
        const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason") || "No reason given"


        if(!interaction.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
        const buttons = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(new MessageButton()
        .setLabel("Permissions")
        .setEmoji("⚙️")
        .setStyle("LINK")
        .setURL("https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions"))

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("❌ | You can't ban a user from the guild!")

        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed],
            components: [buttons],
            ephemeral: true
        })
    }
     if(member === interaction.member) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RED")
            .setDescription("❌ | You can't ban yourself")

            interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
        }
     if (!member) {
        
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("RED")
        .setDescription("❌ | Invalid Member")

        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [embed],
            ephemeral: true
        })
        }
    
        try {
            await interaction.guild.bans.create(member, {
                reason
            })
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("GREEN")
            .setDescription(`✅ | ${member.user.tag} was banned for: ${reason}`)
            
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
        }
        catch(err){
            if (err){
                console.error(err)
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RED")
                .setDescription(`❌ | Failed to ban ${member.user.tag}`)

                return interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [embed]
                })
            }
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed two things below (different method of banning and corrected one mistake). They are notated below.

```js
const {
    MessageEmbed,
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton
} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Ban a user',
    options: [{
            name: "user",
            description: "Choose the user to ban.",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "reason for punishment",
            type: "STRING",
            required: false
        }
    ],
    run: async (client, interaction, options) => {
        const member = interaction.options.getUser("user")
        // .getMember is not a valid function as the type specified above is "USER"
        const reason = interaction.options.getString("reason") || "No reason given"


        if (!interaction.member.permissions.has("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
            const buttons = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(new MessageButton()
                    .setLabel("Permissions")
                    .setEmoji("⚙️")
                    .setStyle("LINK")
                    .setURL("https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions"))

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RED")
                .setDescription("❌ | You can't ban a user from the guild!")

            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed],
                components: [buttons],
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
        if (member === interaction.member) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RED")
                .setDescription("❌ | You can't ban yourself")

            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
        }
        if (!member) {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RED")
                .setDescription("❌ | Invalid Member")

            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed],
                ephemeral: true
            })
        }
// changed up the part below
        try {
            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("GREEN")
                .setDescription(`✅ | ${member.user.tag} was banned for: ${reason}`)

            interaction.reply({
                embeds: [embed]
            })
            return member.ban({
                reason: reason
            })
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err)
                const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("RED")
                    .setDescription(`❌ | Failed to ban ${member.user.tag}`)

                return interaction.reply({
                    embeds: [embed]
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but instead of `member.ban` I have to use `interaction.guild.ban.create(member, {
reason
})` because `member.ban` is not a function.